# No logs from Airflow tasks running in BashOperator

Tags: bash, logging, airflow

After upgrading form Airflow 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 I’m missing some basic logs from BashOperator.

- Airflow Version: 2.2.0
- Python version: 3.7.10
- OS: Amazon Linux 4.14.252-195.483.amzn2.x86_64

Here’s a test Dag that should fail:

```
dag = DAG('darren_test', default_args = default_args, schedule_interval = '* * * * *')

templated_command = """
    ech "This task should fail {{ execution_date }}"
"""

darren_test_task = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'darren_test_task',
    bash_command = templated_command,
    dag = dag)
```

Logs from Airflow 2.1.3

```
*** Reading local file: /data/logs/airflow/darren_test/darren_test_task/2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00/1.log
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,014] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,030] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,030] {{taskinstance.py:1241}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,030] {{taskinstance.py:1242}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,030] {{taskinstance.py:1243}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,062] {{taskinstance.py:1262}} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): darren_test_task> on 2021-10-27 00:01:00+00:00
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,064] {{base_task_runner.py:141}} INFO - Running on host: dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22 12:37:32,064] {{base_task_runner.py:142}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'darren_test', 'darren_test_task', 'scheduled__2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00', '--job-id', '40', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/darren_test.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpp954_9bo', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpp_no352f']
[2021-11-22 12:37:35,330] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task [[34m2021-11-22 12:37:35,329[0m] {{[34mdagbag.py:[0m500}} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from /data/R_Scripts/dags/darren_test.py[0m
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,103] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task Running <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [running]> on host dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task     sys.exit(main())
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task     args.func(args)
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,132] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,133] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task     return func(*args, **kwargs)
...
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,135] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 188, in execute
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,135] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task     f'Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}.'
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,135] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 40: Subtask darren_test_task airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 127.
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,167] {{local_task_job.py:212}} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to failed. Terminating instance.
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,171] {{process_utils.py:100}} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 21664
[2021-11-22 12:37:37,177] {{process_utils.py:66}} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=21664, status='terminated', exitcode=<Negsignal.SIGTERM: -15>, started='12:37:31') (21664) terminated with exit code Negsignal.SIGTERM
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,681] {{taskinstance.py:903}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task 2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,697] {{taskinstance.py:903}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task 2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,697] {{taskinstance.py:1094}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,697] {{taskinstance.py:1095}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,697] {{taskinstance.py:1096}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,712] {{taskinstance.py:1114}} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): darren_test_task> on 2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,713] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running on host: dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22 17:49:35,713] {{base_task_runner.py:134}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'darren_test', 'darren_test_task', '2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00', '--job-id', '6', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/darren_test.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp9gcomh3z', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpfy1j62e2']
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,329] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task [[34m2021-11-22 17:49:37,328[0m] {{[34mdagbag.py:[0m496}} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from /data/R_Scripts/dags/darren_test.py
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,768] {{subprocess.py:52}} INFO - Tmp dir root location:
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,769] {{subprocess.py:63}} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', '\n    ech "This task should fail 2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00"']
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,780] {{subprocess.py:74}} INFO - Output:
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,793] {{subprocess.py:78}} INFO - bash: line 1: ech: command not found
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,794] {{subprocess.py:82}} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,829] {{taskinstance.py:1462}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1164, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1282, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1312, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 176, in execute
    raise AirflowException('Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code.')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code.
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,833] {{taskinstance.py:1512}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=darren_test, task_id=darren_test_task, execution_date=20211027T000100, start_date=20211122T174935, end_date=20211122T174937
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,885] {{logging_mixin.py:109}} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:102 PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
[2021-11-22 17:49:37,885] {{email.py:208}} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,508] {{email.py:220}} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['darren@#####.com']
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,885] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task Running <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task 2021-10-27T00:01:00+00:00 [running]> on host dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     sys.exit(main())
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     args.func(args)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,890] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 91, in wrapper
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 238, in task_run
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 66, in _run_task_by_selected_method
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,891] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     _run_raw_task(args, ti)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 153, in _run_raw_task
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     error_file=args.error_file,
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1164, in _run_raw_task
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1282, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,892] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,893] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1312, in _execute_task
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,893] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,893] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 176, in execute
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,893] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task     raise AirflowException('Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code.')
[2021-11-22 17:49:38,893] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Job 6: Subtask darren_test_task airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code.
[2021-11-22 17:49:39,072] {{local_task_job.py:151}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

There are 2 important pieces on information logged here

1. The command that was run:

   ```
   `Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'darren_test', 'darren_test_task', ...
   ```
2. The stderr from the bash task is displayed: `INFO - bash: line 1: ech: command not found`

Logs from Airflow 2.2.0:

```
*** Reading local file: /data/logs/airflow/darren_test/darren_test_task/2021-10-27T00:05:00+00:00/1.log
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:05:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:05:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1241}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1242}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1243}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{taskinstance.py:1262}} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): darren_test_task> on 2021-10-27 00:05:00+00:00
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{base_task_runner.py:141}} INFO - Running on host: dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22, 13:38:14 ] {{base_task_runner.py:142}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'darren_test', 'darren_test_task', 'scheduled__2021-10-27T00:05:00+00:00', '--job-id', '46', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/darren_test.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp1a0wtk4o', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpmz8211qn']
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task [[34m2021-11-22, 13:38:19 [0m] {{[34mdagbag.py:[0m500}} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from /data/R_Scripts/dags/darren_test.py[0m
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{local_task_job.py:207}} WARNING - Recorded pid 22016 does not match the current pid 22036
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{process_utils.py:100}} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 22036
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task Running <TaskInstance: darren_test.darren_test_task scheduled__2021-10-27T00:05:00+00:00 [running]> on host dst1.darren.######.local
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     sys.exit(main())
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     args.func(args)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 292, in task_run
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     _run_raw_task(args, ti)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 184, in _run_raw_task
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     error_file=args.error_file,
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1324, in _run_raw_task
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1443, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1499, in _execute_task
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     result = execute_callable(context=context)
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 188, in execute
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task     f'Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}.'
[2021-11-22, 13:38:19 ] {{base_task_runner.py:126}} INFO - Job 46: Subtask darren_test_task airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 127.
[2021-11-22, 13:38:20 ] {{process_utils.py:66}} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=22036, status='terminated', exitcode=1, started='12:38:14') (22036) terminated with exit code 1
```

The 2 important pieces of information that we had in v2.1.3 are gone.
No Running...” to show the bash command and for the error it just says `Bash command failed` without the actual stderr.
In this simple case it’s not so much of an issue, but for complex DAGs with multiple dependant tasks it becomes impossible to troubleshoot any issues.

This is the logging configuration which is the same for both Airflow versions tested

```
[logging]
base_log_folder = /data/logs/airflow
remote_logging = False
remote_log_conn_id =
google_key_path =
remote_base_log_folder =
encrypt_s3_logs = False
logging_level = INFO
fab_logging_level = INFO
logging_config_class = custom_logging_config.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG
colored_console_log = True
colored_log_format = [%(blue)s%(asctime)s%(reset)s] {{%(blue)s%(filename)s:%(reset)s%(lineno)d}} %(log_color)s%(levelname)s%(reset)s - %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s
colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter
log_format = [%(asctime)s] {{%(filename)s:%(lineno)d}} %(levelname)s - %(message)s
simple_log_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s
task_log_prefix_template =
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /data/logs/airflow/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log
task_log_reader = task
extra_loggers =
extra_logger_names =
worker_log_server_port = 8793
```

And this is the logging_config_class which is also the same for both Airflow versions tested

```
"""Airflow logging settings"""

import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Dict, Union
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException

# TODO: Logging format and level should be configured
# in this file instead of from airflow.cfg. Currently
# there are other log format and level configurations in
# settings.py and cli.py. Please see AIRFLOW-1455.
LOG_LEVEL: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()


# Flask appbuilder's info level log is very verbose,
# so it's set to 'WARN' by default.
FAB_LOG_LEVEL: str = conf.get('logging', 'FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()
LOG_FORMAT: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOG_FORMAT')
COLORED_LOG_FORMAT: str = conf.get('logging', 'COLORED_LOG_FORMAT')
COLORED_LOG: bool = conf.getboolean('logging', 'COLORED_CONSOLE_LOG')
COLORED_FORMATTER_CLASS: str = conf.get('logging', 'COLORED_FORMATTER_CLASS')
BASE_LOG_FOLDER: str = conf.get('logging', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')
PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER: str = conf.get('scheduler', 'CHILD_PROCESS_LOG_DIRECTORY')
DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION: str = conf.get('logging', 'DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION')
FILENAME_TEMPLATE: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOG_FILENAME_TEMPLATE')
PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE: str = conf.get('logging', 'LOG_PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE')
DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG: Dict[str, Any] = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'airflow': {'format': LOG_FORMAT},
    'airflow_coloured': {
        'format': COLORED_LOG_FORMAT if COLORED_LOG else LOG_FORMAT,
        'class': COLORED_FORMATTER_CLASS if COLORED_LOG else 'logging.Formatter',
    },
},
'filters': {
    'mask_secrets': {
        '()': 'airflow.utils.log.secrets_masker.SecretsMasker',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.RedirectStdHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow_coloured',
        'stream': 'sys.stdout',
        'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
    },
    'task': {
        'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow',
        'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
        'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
    },
    'processor': {
        'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow',
        'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
        'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'airflow.processor': {
        'handlers': ['processor'],
        'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'airflow.task': {
        'handlers': ['task'],
        'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        'propagate': False,
        'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
    },
    'flask_appbuilder': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': FAB_LOG_LEVEL,
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
'root': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': LOG_LEVEL,
    'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
},
}

EXTRA_LOGGER_NAMES: str = conf.get('logging', 'EXTRA_LOGGER_NAMES', fallback=None)
if EXTRA_LOGGER_NAMES:
new_loggers = {
    logger_name.strip(): {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        'propagate': True,
    }
    for logger_name in EXTRA_LOGGER_NAMES.split(",")
}
DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers'].update(new_loggers)

DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG: Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, Any]]] = {
'handlers': {
    'processor_manager': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow',
        'filename': DAG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOG_LOCATION,
        'mode': 'a',
        'maxBytes': 104857600,  # 100MB
        'backupCount': 5,
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'airflow.processor_manager': {
        'handlers': ['processor_manager'],
        'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        'propagate': False,
    }
},
}

# Only update the handlers and loggers when CONFIG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOGGER is set.
# This is to avoid exceptions when initializing RotatingFileHandler multiple times
# in multiple processes.
if os.environ.get('CONFIG_PROCESSOR_MANAGER_LOGGER') == 'True':
DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'].update(DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'])
DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers'].update(DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers'])

# Manually create log directory for processor_manager handler as RotatingFileHandler
# will only create file but not the directory.
processor_manager_handler_config: Dict[str, Any] = DEFAULT_DAG_PARSING_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers'][
    'processor_manager'
]
directory: str = os.path.dirname(processor_manager_handler_config['filename'])
Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True, mode=0o755)

##################
# Remote logging #
##################

# All of this section is commented as we don't use it for now.
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.
Thank you.

**Update:** in comparing the logs I noticed that Airflow 2.2.0 doesn't have any of the logs from `{{ subprocess.py }}`. Does anyone know why that is? Is it related with my custom log config class maybe? Thanks!